# SQL select into a variable, resulting in incorrect value of variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The problem I am having is a select seeming to use an old value of a variable, BUT ONLY WHEN VALUES DON'T EXIST.

The first run of the script, neither group id is in the table, so both select statements on their own should return AnswerGroupID = NULL. Then subsequent runs of script both groups should exist and the queries return a valid int, which is then used to delete before re-creating.

I have a workaround, but I would like to understand what is going wrong to prevent errors like this in the future.

The basic structure of the tables is:
Answer table has a list of answers (one row per answer) all linked via a group id (int column).
AnswerGroup table has the group level properties (groupID is a normal int column, table has a separate primary key)

using SQL Server 2008.

```
--comments to cut out irrelevant code

DECLARE @GroupNameToAdd VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @AnswerGroupID INT

SET @GroupNameToAdd = 'group1'
PRINT @GroupNameToAdd -- prints 'group1'

select @AnswerGroupID = a.groupID
from mySchema.Answers a
join mySchema.AnswerGroup ag
on a.groupID = ag.groupID
where a.AnswerValue = @GroupNameToAdd

-- ** result of above query is null first time
-- ** result of above query is 1234 subsequent times

-- if (@AnswerGroupID is not null, delete existing entries)
-- add new entry
SET @AnswerGroupID = MAX(groupID)+1
FROM mySchema.AnswerGroup

-- ** result of above query would now be 1234 if re-run here**

SET @GroupNameToAdd = 'group2'
PRINT @GroupNameToAdd -- prints 'group2'

select @AnswerGroupID = a.groupID
from mySchema.Answers a
join mySchema.AnswerGroup ag
on a.groupID = ag.groupID
where a.AnswerValue = @GroupNameToAdd

-- ** HERE IT SELECTS 1234 first time (as if it was using old value of @GroupNameToAdd) when it should be NULL
-- ** subsequent times it selects 1235 (correctly)

-- if (@AnswerGroupID is not null, delete existing entries)
-- add new entry includes line:
```

Due to the incorrect selection, the query deletes the newly inserted first entry.

THE WORKAROUND:

before the second selection statement

```
SET @AnswerGroupID = NULL
```

Comment: Your title says "select into" and you mention "delete" and "add new rows" in the comments.  But I see no code that actually modifies the tables.

Comment: After doing all that code simplifying for submission, I have an educated guess as to what is happening, it could be that the second select is not setting the @AnswerGroupID, so it just retains it's value from inserting the first group. Could this be correct behaviour of selecting into a variable?

Comment: @m2o2r2g2 is select returns no rows of course it does not set the variable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, forgot to finish typing the title! The add new rows has been omitted from the submission as stated at the top in the comment (my testing has shown it is only the insertion of the group id that makes any difference). I am reluctant to post the insert specifics (for company disclosure reasons).

Comment: @zespri - just to confirm, as I think that might be the solution, if the select returns nothing, it does not reset the variable to NULL (as the result of the query is no value which to me implies null)

Comment: @m2o2r2g2 . . . That is correct.  You can run the sample code in the answer below.  It is simpler but clearly illustrates the problem.

Comment: @m2o2r2g2 refer to here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330%28v=sql.100%29.aspx You are interested in this bit: "*SELECT `@local_variable` is typically used to return a single value into the variable. However, when expression is the name of a column, it can return multiple values. If the SELECT statement returns more than one value, the variable is assigned the last value that is returned. If the SELECT statement returns no rows, the variable retains its present value.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a guess.  If no rows are returned by a query, then no assignment happens.  So, the following returns "1":

```
declare @v int = 1;

select @v = 2
from (select 10 as c) t
where c = 2;

select @v;
```

In the second query, you are setting `@GroupNameToAdd` *after* a row has been inserted.  Presumably, the new name is not in the tables used by the query.  So, there are no matches to the query so `@AnswerGroupID` does not get reassigned.